# Laws of Logarithms Issue

Tags: logarithms

I have trouble with this maths assignment.
Can you tell me what was wrong?

Thanks for your help!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/57ubtuslqjriqvd/zrongg.png

Comment: I think the problem might come from the division. I often make mistakes with these divisions!

Comment: Please use latex instead of linking a picture. The last "+" of your expansion should be a "-".

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll use it next time. Oh I see, that's because of the division right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quotient Property of Logarithms states that for $X,Y,b\in \mathbb{R}^+, b\neq{1},$ 
$$\log_b{\frac{X}{Y}}=\log_bX-\log_bY$$
Let $X=x^2$, and $Y=yz^3$.  Thus
$$\log_b{\frac{x^2}{yz^3}}=\log_bx^2-\log_byz^3$$
The Product Property of Logarithms states virtually the same formula, except
$$\log_b{XY}=\log_bX+\log_bY$$
Let $X=y$, and $Y=z^3$.  Thus
$$\log_b{yz^3}=\log_by+\log_bz^3$$
Therefore our entire expansion is
 $$\log_b{\frac{x^2}{yz^3}}=\log_bx^2-(\log_by+\log_bz^3)$$
Finally, the Power Property of Logarithms states that, for $c\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\log_bX^c=c\log_bX$$
Thus 
$$\log_b{\frac{x^2}{yz^3}}=\log_bx^2-\log_by-\log_bz^3=2\log_bx-\log_by-3\log_bz$$

Comment: fixed it...made slight calculation error with my distribution of the negative...  I think the -1 was harsh, but not everyone can be forgiving i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_a\left(\dfrac{x^2}{yz^3}\right)=2\log_ax-\log_a(yz^3)=2\log_ax-\log_ay-3\log_az$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it, silly mistake! :)

Comment: @Minimorum If this answer is what you wanted, click on the green check mark so as to select this as the answer which helped you.

Comment: It helped me, but the description of Iceman is more developed... Thanks anyway!